# Is it safe to re-index an AWS Cloudsearch index while another indexing operation is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I've just started a re-index of my Cloudsearch index because I've added a new field and changed the data type (text to literal) of another field. I've just realized I accidentally set the literal field to be non-searchable, and need to change.

The full re-index should probably take about 3-4 hours, but I'd like start over. I'm sort of nervous about re-indexing while another re-index is running, because there's no option to let you cancel an in-flight indexing operation. I can't see anything in the docs about this. Is it safe?

Comment: I don't have an actual answer for you but my gut feeling is that it's safe. If it weren't, I expect CloudSearch wouldn't allow you to do it. I'm fairly sure I've done it at some point and it's possible that it had some subtly side effects but nothing disastrous happened.

Comment: I actually went ahead and did it before it finished indexing. I haven't seen any adverse effects. Maybe it cancels any currently running index operations when a new one is started, or it's designed such that multiple indexing runs won't affect each other.